# Перерендер компонента react-table

Tags: reactjs

Использую библиотеку react-table, в ней у меня есть компонент фильтрации по столбцу, хочу получать строки таблицы, когда происходит фильтрация.

Решил сделать это через useState (бумеранг в дочерний компонент)

Прокидываю в компонент таблицы функцию useState через пропсы:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(null)

<UniversalTable
    data={incidents}
    columns={columns}
    setFilteredData={setFilteredData}
/>
```

Затем, внутри компонента таблицы вызываю со значением useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('render')
    setFilteredData(rows)
}, [rows])
```

и, если в родителе отслеживать изменения значения useState и выводить в консоль что-либо, то зацикливается и получается бесконечный вывод, если вызвать setFilteredData(rows) вне useEffect то render будет также бесконечно выводиться в консоль

rows достается из useTable:

```
const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data
        },
        useFilters,
        useSortBy
    )
```